# Create a new virtualhost with phabricator virtualhost

Tags: apache, playframework-2.0, httpd.conf, phabricator

I have one virtualhost in site available (etc/apache2/sites-available/phabricator.conf)

```
Alias /phabricator/ /var/www/phabricator/phabricator/webroot/
<VirtualHost *:80>`
ServerName test.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/phabricator/phabricator/webroot
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]

<Directory "/var/www/phabricator/phabricator/webroot">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log comb
</VirtualHost>
```

when i type in url test.net i am redirected on phabricator page

i want add a new virtualhost to point on playframework application sites-available/default-ssl i think not a good file but every where is same problem :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ServerName tets.net
   ProxyPass  /excluded !
   ProxyPass /test2 http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse /test2 http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

but the second virtual host never work i have this error : The requested URL could not be retrieved.
on root i arrive on phabricator on all other url nothing working

Answer (score 0):

**Always Match Slashes when using ProxyPass**

Make sure 127.0.0.1:9000 is reachable, once you do, define your proxypass directives correctly, matching slashes in the source and the target. That is, if the source is a directory, the target must be a directory, if the source is a file the target must be a file, directories end with /, in this case since `http://127.0.0.1:9000` is a directory the correct resulting proxypass directive looks like:

```
ProxyPass /test2/ http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse /test2/ http://127.0.0.1:9000/
```

Comment: Don't understand your explanations, anyway it is working with simpy start play with another way as windows (in background) : "nohup activator testProd" nd "activator stage" thank you ! i access by server:9000 more secure